# Authorization for anonymous user (automatic authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

**UPDATE**: Unfortunately, a Windows reboot solved this issue -.-

---

In our ASP.NET Core (1.0 RC2) application, we have the following requirement: only users from the internal network should be able to access some "Debug" pages (hosted by MVC Core). It's a public website and we don't have user logins, instead we managed it until now with a custom IP-address based authorization (note: this is not a security risk in our case, because we have a proxy in between, so the IP address cannot be spoofed from outside).

We want to implement such an IP-address based authorization in ASP.NET Core, as well. We use a custom policy `"DebugPages"` for this and corresponding `[Authorize(Policy="DebugPages")]` definitions on the MVC controller. Then we noticed, that we must have an authenticated user to get the `AuthorizeAttribute` to jump in and we create one in the request pipeline, which yields to the following code in Startup.cs (shortened for brevity):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "DebugPages",
            policy => policy.RequireAssertion(
                async context => await MyIPAuthorization.IsAuthorizedAsync()));
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("anonymous"));
        await next.Invoke();
    });

    ...
}
```

Now this ***works fine*** when run in Debug by Visual Studio 2015 (with IIS Express).
But unfortunately it ***doesn't work*** when run directly by `dotnet run` (with Kestrel) from the command line. In this case we get the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
```

The same error occurs when we provide the current Windows principal instead of the principal with a custom anonymous identity -- so everytime when the user is *automatic*-ally authenticated...

So, why is there a difference between hosting in IIS Express and Kestrel? Any suggestions how to solve the issue?

Comment: This part of code works fine with kestrel(dotnet run) for me. It seems the  reason of exception is not related with this code.

Comment: Damn... I just rebooted and now everything is working fine. I don't know what happened... good old Windows, I fear (_if it's not good - reboot!_).

Comment: Hello. I have the same issue. Not in Windows but in docker too. The version is Core 1.0. I've investigated the problem and have seen that the context.Authentication.HttpAuthhenticationFeature.Handler is null when you use Kestrel and not null when you use IIS. I asume that the trick is in the .UseIISIntegration() in Program.cs

Answer (score 2):

So, after some research, as I mentioned in the comments, I have found that httpContext.Authentication.HttpAuthhenticationFeature.Handler is null, when you starts the application under the "selfhosted" kestrel. But when you use IIS the Handler has instantiated by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.AuthenticationHandler. This specific handler implementation is part of the .UseIISIntegration() in Program.cs.

So, I've decided to use a part of this implementation in my App and handle nonauthenticated requests.

For my WebAPI (without any Views) service I use IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation that uses behind the scenes OAuth2IntrospectionAuthentication and JwtBearerAuthentication.

Create files

KestrelAuthenticationMiddleware.cs

```
public class KestrelAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public KestrelAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var existingPrincipal = context.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>()?.User;
        var handler = new KestrelAuthHandler(context, existingPrincipal);
        AttachAuthenticationHandler(handler);
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        finally
        {
            DetachAuthenticationhandler(handler);
        }
    }

    private void AttachAuthenticationHandler(KestrelAuthHandler handler)
    {
        var auth = handler.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>();
        if (auth == null)
        {
            auth = new HttpAuthenticationFeature();
            handler.HttpContext.Features.Set(auth);
        }
        handler.PriorHandler = auth.Handler;
        auth.Handler = handler;
    }

    private void DetachAuthenticationhandler(KestrelAuthHandler handler)
    {
        var auth = handler.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>();
        if (auth != null)
        {
            auth.Handler = handler.PriorHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

KestrelAuthHandler.cs

```
internal class KestrelAuthHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
{
    internal KestrelAuthHandler(HttpContext httpContext, ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        HttpContext = httpContext;
        User = user;
    }

    internal HttpContext HttpContext { get; }

    internal ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }

    internal IAuthenticationHandler PriorHandler { get; set; }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticateContext context)
    {
        if (User != null)
        {
            context.Authenticated(User, properties: null, description: null);
        }
        else
        {
            context.NotAuthenticated();
        }


        if (PriorHandler != null)
        {
            return PriorHandler.AuthenticateAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(ChallengeContext context)
    {
        bool handled = false;
        switch (context.Behavior)
        {
            case ChallengeBehavior.Automatic:
                // If there is a principal already, invoke the forbidden code path
                if (User == null)
                {
                    goto case ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized;
                }
                else
                {
                    goto case ChallengeBehavior.Forbidden;
                }
            case ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized:
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                // We would normally set the www-authenticate header here, but IIS does that for us.
                break;
            case ChallengeBehavior.Forbidden:
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                handled = true; // No other handlers need to consider this challenge.
                break;
        }
        context.Accept();


        if (!handled && PriorHandler != null)
        {
            return PriorHandler.ChallengeAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public void GetDescriptions(DescribeSchemesContext context)
    {
        if (PriorHandler != null)
        {
            PriorHandler.GetDescriptions(context);
        }
    }

    public Task SignInAsync(SignInContext context)
    {
        // Not supported, fall through
        if (PriorHandler != null)
        {
            return PriorHandler.SignInAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SignOutAsync(SignOutContext context)
    {
        // Not supported, fall through
        if (PriorHandler != null)
        {
            return PriorHandler.SignOutAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And in the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<KestrelAuthenticationMiddleware>();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = Configuration[AppConstants.Authority],
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ScopeName = Configuration[AppConstants.ScopeName],
            ScopeSecret = Configuration[AppConstants.ScopeSecret],
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```